# I found different results developing the divergence of the advection flux

Tags: chain-rule, divergence-operator

There's something I don't get with the divergence in the conservation law
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot f(\rho) = 0
$$
with $$f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$$ the flux.
We can write, using the chain rule, $\nabla \cdot f(\rho) = f'(\rho) \cdot \nabla \rho$, right ?

So if we take $f(\rho) = \boldsymbol{v}\rho $ we have $$\nabla \cdot f(\rho) = \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \nabla \rho$$.

But at the same time, if we develop the divergence of $\boldsymbol{v}\rho$ and develop using the product rule, we have
$$\nabla \cdot (\boldsymbol{v}\rho) = \boldsymbol{v}\cdot \nabla \rho + \rho \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{v}$$

So what did I miss ?

Comment: When $\boldsymbol v$ is a constant, $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol v=0$.  When it is not a constant , then $f'(\rho)\neq \boldsymbol v$ .

Comment: Further, when $\boldsymbol v$ is not a function of $\rho$, then $\boldsymbol v\rho$ is not a valid substitute for $f(\rho)$.

Comment: @Graham Kemp, since $f$ is a function of $\rho$, I thought that $f'(\rho)$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\rho$. Hence my conclusion: $f'(\rho) = \boldsymbol{v}$.
And why $\boldsymbol{v}\rho$ is not a good substitute ? Because I see a lot of studies of this law, and then examples with $f(\rho)=\boldsymbol{v} \rho$, with $\boldsymbol{v}$ not necessary constant as the 'advection flux'

Comment: If $\boldsymbol v$ is not a constant, then $\boldsymbol v\rho$ is not a function of $\rho$ alone - it is *also* a function of $\boldsymbol v$ and hence you need to use the Product Rule.  In short the answer to "why do these things behave differently" is because "they are not the same thing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule you’ve written is only valid if $f$ only depends on $\boldsymbol x$ through $\rho$, which is not the case if $\boldsymbol v$ also depends on $\boldsymbol x$.

Comment: Here is how I thought it was, for all functions:
$\nabla \cdot f(\rho) = \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i(\rho)}{\partial x_i} = \sum_i \frac{\partial f_i}{\partial \rho} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_i}$
I believe you, but I don't understand why..

Comment: You can't write $\boldsymbol v(\boldsymbol x )\rho(x)$ as a function of $\rho$ only, so that chain rule does not apply.  You could write $f(\rho, \boldsymbol x) = \boldsymbol v(\boldsymbol x )\rho(x)$ and apply the chain rule, noting both the ways that $f$ depends on $\boldsymbol x$.